# Python, matplotlib, plotting with dates

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, plot

this is my first time asking a question here. I am very new to programming and not very gifted, I am currently working on a small little program where I try to plot EURUSD prices against dates, I have been experiencing a problem of not being able to plot the dates on the x-axis. I have been looking around the web for help and answers but without any great luck. Anyway, heres my code so far:

```
j=1
dates = []
price = []
with open('EURUSD_day.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print (f)
    for row in reader:
        if j > 1:
        dates.append(row[1])
        dates.append(float(row[6]))
    j = j + 1
import datetime as dt
dates = []
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y').date() for d in dates]
y = range(len(x))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
plt.plot
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate
plt.show()
```

I thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues you have in your code. Actually more than just a couple. First you declare `dates=[]` and fill it up with dates you read from a file, and you do it weird too!

You fill in the dates into a list that looks something like this:

["String element", float, "String element", float ....]

Then you forget all about that because you declare again a new empty list `dates=[]` right after the `import` statement, and then you go through that empty list with a generator

```
[dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y').date() for d in dates]
```

creating empty datetime objects. And finally you never actually call the plot function because

```
>>> plt.plot
<function plot at 0x04607C48>
```

you never send in any actual data. Your plot lacks any arguments: `plt.plot([1,2,3,4])`. And again at the end you repeat the same error because

```
>>> plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate
<bound method Figure.autofmt_xdate of <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x02F97FB0>>
```

you again never call the actual method that autoformats your dates `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate`.

Please verify you really have all you need to continue on with the next step of your program. 
That means:

1. You read in data from file in a meaningful format you can process. That means if you're planing on parsing your dates with `striptime` that you have a list of dates in the format `%m/%d/%Y` : `[01/1/2012, 01/2/2012...]`
2. That after you parse your dates with `striptime` you have a list of datetime.datetime objects! (A meaningful list of objects)
3. That you actually send them to be plotted.

Also to plot them use `plt.plot_dates` function which takes care of most of the nice date formatting for you.

I strongly recommend that you start in IDLE and start defining small short and clear functions and work your way step by step towards a complete sollution. Hope it was of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment, because on this stackexchange I do not yet have 50 reputation. However, this should be a comment, and not an answer, because it does not really answer your question.

There are quite a few problems with your code. The first is that you actually need to plot your data:

Your plt.plot line should read something like:

```
plt.plot(x, y)
```

I'm not completely sure this will work, because I think pyplot requires numbers for both the x and y axes, and your list for x are currently strings. This also means that changing the format of your x axis should problems there, because what a DateFormatter expects is a datetime object, and not a string.

And that's ignoring the syntax error for the following:

```
for row in reader:
        if j > 1:
        dates.append(row[1])
        dates.append(float(row[6]))
```

This is not valid python code. Presumably you mean the following?

```
for row in reader:
    if j > 1:
        dates.append(row[1])
        dates.append(float(row[6]))
```

In any case, why not convert these to datetime.date when you read them from your file?